# Ubuntu 16.04 server install = 140GB?

Tags: system-installation

Local disk space 2.68 TB total / 2.54 TB free / 142.62 GB used

Virtual memory 7.70 GB total / 0 bytes used

This is a fresh install, how do I go about figuring out what took all that space, I'm a novice.

Output of `df -h`:
[image: df -h output]

Webmin output:
[image: webmin output]

Comment: Checkout  the program `du`. See `man du` for usage.

Comment: thanks, the largest thing i can find is 435MB, i don't get it :/

Comment: Show the output of `sudo df -kh`...

Comment: @BJAN: The output of `df -h` shows it is using 3GB which is perfectly normal. Webmin seems to show you wrong data there. And please use the [edit] function to include requested data directly to your question. :)

Comment: I agree with @Videonauth. The install looks normal. A person _could_ research Webmin to see the command used to get that info.

Comment: Thank you for helping, it seems like that, yes.

Comment: when you use LVM, the partition is uses is normally 100% used by the LVM. But your real use is how much of the logical volume inside  it uses. You show the normal 3GB. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On any hard drive, a partial amount of space is reserved for those kind of information:

- File descriptors, file table and inode table in Unix
- LVM metadata information

When using large hard drive, this may take hundred of gigabyte, as this space is proportional of the partition size.

You can have a look of space used by inode :

```
sudo tune2fs -l /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root | grep -i Block
```

Your result should looking like

```
Block count:              488378368
Reserved block count:     24418916
Free blocks:              296161792
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      907
Blocks per group:         32768
Inode blocks per group:   512
Flex block group size:    16
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
Journal backup:           inode blocks
```

Do `Reserved block count` * `Block size` / (1024 * 1024 * 1024) = **93.15GB** reserved in my case (for a 2TB hard drive).